# An object 'OBJECT' of type StaticResource was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: mavensmate

When I try to modify / save a static resource (stylesheet) in VScode, using Mavensmate - I get this error.

I'm pretty certain it's mavensmate doing this. I have tried changing the tooling API setting, but nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Comment: I get the same error on VSCode with MavensMate.